# Apache Virtual Host and CA Intermediate File

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

Listed below is an example from an Apache virtual host file.  I was curious if there was a particular order that the SSLCertificate, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and the SSLCACertificateFile should be in?  Should the intermediate certificate file from the CA be listed first?  Is there a hierarchy to how these are processed?  The CA intermediate file is needed in this case to support the 2048 bit SSL certificate that is being used.

```
SSLEngine ON
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/intermediate-ca-file.crt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ordering of SSLCACertificateFile entries within the .conf file does not matter because the trust chain that is followed is taken from the certificates them self and assembled during the loading of the HTTPDs

Comment: @user7918: Thanks for the information and the update.  I was worried that it might create some problem by having it listed last.